# PyCUDA mem_get_ipc_handle gives LogicError: cuIpcGetMemHandle failed: operation not supported

Tags: cuda, ipc, pycuda

I am trying to execute the code [here](https://gist.github.com/lebedov/5179201). I get the following error:

```
orig:  [0.36975162 0.08511397 0.16306844 0.4015488  0.25104857 0.30606773 0.24524205 0.13792656]
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\My\Desktop\test_codes\pycuda4.py", line 28, in func1
    h = drv.mem_get_ipc_handle(x_gpu.ptr)
LogicError: cuIpcGetMemHandle failed: operation not supported
```

I am using Python 3.7, CUDA 9.2 in Windows 7 x64 environment. Is CUDA `IPCMemoryHandle` not supported in Windows? Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interprocess-communication) is that CUDA IPC functionality is only supported on Linux.

However, the driver API (upon which PyCUDA is based) [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g6f1b5be767b275f016523b2ac49ebec1) indicate:

> IPC functionality is restricted to devices with support for unified addressing on Linux and Windows operating systems. IPC functionality on Windows is restricted to GPUs in TCC mode

Therefore if you can put your windows GPU in [TCC mode](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/tesla_compute_cluster.htm) (via `nvidia-smi` tool) then I think it should probably work/be supported.  GeForce GPUs cannot be put in TCC mode.  Most Titan and Quadro GPUs can be placed in TCC mode.  Most Tesla GPUs on windows should automatically be in TCC mode.  Note that putting your GPU in TCC mode means it cannot host a display any longer.

In recent CUDA toolkits, IPC support has been added for both WDDM and TCC usage in windows (the underlying mechanisms are different).  The CUDA IPC sample code demonstrates all flavors (linux, windows TCC, windows WDDM).

Comment: Is there any other way to make device memory IPC work in Windows?

Comment: Updated my answer, it should address this question.  Apart from what is described in the answer, there is no other way to share device memory or device memory pointers between processes on Windows.  Of course you could copy the data from device memory to host memory, and use standard IPC techniques, if you wish.  Presumably this is not what you had in mind.